# django recreate dropped table

Tags: python, django, orm

I dropped a table manually cause while changing the model I made a very bad mistake. So anyway ... how can I recreate it ? I have tried :

```
- Delete the migrate folder of that app
- delete from django_migrations where app='main'
- makemigrations main
- migrate main
```

But it stops at the first table. Which is there :-( and my Table `message` in that case is not recreated. In `0001_initial.py` I have the correct entry for my table

```
migrations.CreateModel(
        name='Message',
        fields=[
            ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
            ('created_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
            ('updated_at', models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)),
            ('unread', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
            ('subject', models.CharField(max_length=120)),
            ('freetext', models.TextField(null=True)),
            ('from_user', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='from_user', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
            ('to_user', models.ForeignKey(on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, related_name='to_user', to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)),
        ],
    ),
```

Is there way to start this manually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next time when you rollback:

1. Go into the migrations folder in your app.
2. Look for the migration file where you would like to go back to. (for example 0012_post_category.py)
3. go in the terminal write: ./manage.py migrate yourAppName 0012 (this is just an example number) and hit enter
4. if everything goes well. Delete the other migrations which came after this number in your migrations folder.

Do not just delete migrations! Hope that helps.

Comment: yes this helps. Next time I will do that :-) for my specific problem I have created a file `0002_message.py` containg just the create for table `message`. I have now `0001_initial.py` and `0002_message.py`. I wiped out all entries in `django_migrations` except `0001_initial` and ran `migrate main` and hurray table recreated. At least I do now understand better how this migrate stuff works

Comment: Of course I removed the entries for `message` in `0001_initial.py`

Comment: Ok very good. This is like my standard way if there are problems with the db. In 90% of the cases you can fix the problem like this

Answer (score 2):

I think best way is to write your own migration file.

Under the migration folder create new migration file with DeleteModel method. for instance if your previous migration file name is `'0065_auto_20210318_0000'` so your file migth be:

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('my_app', '0065_auto_20210318_0000'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.DeleteModel(
            name='MyModel',
        ),
    ]
```